# how to make sure 2 apps on 2 different servers but at the same time only 1 app on 1 server running

Tags: linux, process-management

I am having an app written in java, the app is deployed on 2 servers. However I can only launch the app on one server. If I run the app on both servers there will be a conflict. So I'm looking for a solution to make sure my app is only running on one server without having to edit the app's code.

Answer (score 1):

Software for this problem exists since long time: [Pacemaker](https://clusterlabs.org/pacemaker/)

Unfortunately, this is not trivial to configure at all.

If your app is not time-critical, you can also use the simple solution and create a file on shared storage that specifies which server the app is running on and check for that file on startup. But then you have to make sure that the file is deleted when the app crashes and that not both servers start at exactly the same time.

And this is the point where admins decide between a perfect but complicated solution like pacemaker, and own wrapper scripts, which poll for the existence of files or network ports in the hope, that no race condition occurs.

You have to compare the disadvantages of the two alternatives.